# Passing Data for Each User from one Django app to another?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, plotly-dash

In my Django application, users can log in using their username and password. Once logged in, the user makes a selection through a dropdown menu in an app.py created with dash-plotly. I want to retain this selection made by the user in memory and use it as an input for another app.py.

I attempted to use an API, but it didn't provide a user-specific solution.

Do you have any suggestions regarding this matter? Should I try using Models?

I tried API and DjangoDashConsumer and I could not reach the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variable for the purpose